# kotlin logging with lambda parameters

Tags: java-8, log4j2, kotlin

In log4j2 we have a handy feature which is described as

```
// Java-8 style optimization: no need to explicitly check the log level:
// the lambda expression is not evaluated if the TRACE level is not enabled
logger.trace("Some long-running operation returned {}", () -> expensiveOperation());
```

my attempt to use this in kotlin

```
log.debug("random {}", { UUID.randomUUID() })
```

which will print

```
random Function0<java.util.UUID>
```

**How do we use lambda argument logging with kotlin? Or how do we explicitly tell kotlin what method to call?**

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The problem is that `debug()` is overloaded, and has another method taking a vararg Object as argument. Kotlin chooses that overload rather than the one taking a `Supplier<?>` as argument, because it doesn't know that the lambda expression is supposed to be a Supplier.

Just specify it as a Supplier:

```
log.debug("random {}", Supplier { UUID.randomUUID() })
```

Answer (score 2):

Check out https://github.com/MicroUtils/kotlin-logging . It also provide those features:

A convenient and performant logging library wrapping slf4j with Kotlin extensions.

Call log methods, without checking whether the respective log level is enabled:

```
logger.debug { "Some $expensive message!" }
```

Behind the scenes the expensive message do not get evaluated if debug is not enabled:

```
if (logger.isDebugEnabled) logger.debug("Some $expensive message!")
```

Define the logger, without explicitly specifying the class name:

```
// Place definition above class declaration to make field static  
private val logger = KotlinLogging.logger {}
```